# ASP.NET Core 3.1 publish github action self-hosted issue while restore - nupkg used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, github-actions

I have an Asp.Net core 3.1 project for each i have created a github workflow  which runs as self-hosted and publishes and deployment. The self hosted runner is installed in a linux machine. My project has also dependency on two vb.net projects. The publish command command looks like this: dotnet publish --framework netcoreapp3.1 --runtime linux-x64 -c Release.

Problem is that most of the time i try to publish i get an error message telling that nupkg file of the dependent project is used by another process:

> 2023-09-09T14:51:11.8089410Z
> /home/gitrunner/.dotnet/sdk/3.1.426/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/build/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(198,5):
> error : The process cannot access the file
> '/home/gitrunner/actions-runner/_work/ApiProject/ApiProject/Dep1/dep1/bin/Release/dep1.1.0.0.nupkg'
> because it is being used by another process.
> [/home/gitrunner/actions-runner/_work/ApiProject/ApiProject/Dep1/dep1/ApiProject.vbproj]

Any idea what could be the problem? Tried different ways to publish also by restoring first but no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before attempting to publish, clean and rebuild your solution. This can help ensure that all the build artifacts are up-to-date and not locked by other processes.

Comment: Tried cleaning up as well. The issue with this thing is that some time works ok...

Comment: It's possible that another build or publish process is still running and holding a lock on the file. You can use system tools like lsof on Linux to identify processes that might be using the file

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i needed to restore the depended projects first. Restore the main project with --no-dependencies flag and then publish  with --no-release mode. Something like the following:

```
 dotnet restore DependentProject1
 dotnet restore DependentProject2
 dotnet restore MainProject --no-dependencies
 dotnet publish MainProject -c Release --no-restore
```